# Fragment shader position changes when browser zoomed

Tags: javascript, webgl, shader, cocos2d-js

I am using cocos2d-js webgl mode to create a very simple shader effect:

draw a filled circle with a give center position and a radius.

The fragment shader :

```
uniform vec2 position;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float lightSize;

    void main()
    {
        float distance = distance(gl_FragCoord.xy, position);
        if (distance <= lightSize) {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor, 1.0);
        }
        else {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor, 0.0);   
        }
    }
```

This code works fine when the browser is not scaled (100 %).

But, when I try to zoom the browser to 80% or 120%, I found that the circle was drawn with a offset from the center position I set.

I am not sure how to fix this problem to make sure that the circle is always on the CENTER POSITION I set no matter how I zoom the browser.

Any advice will be appreciated, thanks :)

Comment: What value are you setting for `position`? It's a uniform, and the posted code does not show what value you're setting it to.

Answer (score 0):

If your window was (200, 200), then the center was (100, 100). But if your window suddenly becomes (400, 400), (100, 100) is no longer the center, right? That's what "window-space" means: the space relative to the window.

If you want to do computations in a space that is not dependent on the window's properties, then you must transform `gl_FragCoord` into that space. And of course, your `position` must also be in the same space.

A common solution would be to get the size of the window and pass it as a uniform. Then divide `gl_FragCoord.xy` by that size. The center of the window in this space would always be (0.5, 0.5). But you must make sure to update this uniform *whenever* the window changes dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Trying your shader below I see no issues

```js
var fs = `
precision mediump float;
uniform vec2 position;
uniform vec3 lightColor;
uniform float lightSize;

    void main()
    {
        float distance = distance(gl_FragCoord.xy, position);
        if (distance <= lightSize) {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor, 1.0);
        }
        else {
            gl_FragColor = vec4(lightColor, 0.0);   
        }
    }
`;
var vs = `
attribute vec4 a_position;
void main() {
  gl_Position = a_position;
}
`;

var gl = document.querySelector("canvas").getContext("webgl");
var programInfo = twgl.createProgramInfo(gl, [vs, fs]);
var bufferInfo = twgl.createBufferInfoFromArrays(gl, {
  a_position: { 
    numComponents: 2,
    data: [
      -1, -1,
      -1,  1,
       1, -1,
       1, -1,
      -1,  1,
       1,  1,
    ],
  },
});

function render(time) {
  time *= 0.001;
  twgl.resizeCanvasToDisplaySize(gl.canvas);
  gl.viewport(0, 0, gl.canvas.width, gl.canvas.height);

  var uniforms = {
    position: [gl.canvas.width / 2, gl.canvas.height / 2],
    lightColor: [0.5 + Math.sin(time * 10) * 0.25, 0, 0],
    lightSize: 100,
  };    
      
  gl.useProgram(programInfo.program);
  twgl.setBuffersAndAttributes(gl, programInfo, bufferInfo);
  twgl.setUniforms(programInfo, uniforms);
  twgl.drawBufferInfo(gl, gl.TRIANGLES, bufferInfo);
  requestAnimationFrame(render);
}
requestAnimationFrame(render);
```

```css
body { margin: 0; }
canvas { display: block; width: 100vw; height: 100vh; }
```

```html
<script src="https://twgljs.org/dist/twgl.min.js"></script>
<canvas></canvas>
```

What are you setting position to? The code above is setting it to `gl.canvas.width / 2, gl.canvas.height / 2` which is the middle of the canvas